# Can't compile python bindings using boost-python on OS X

Tags: python, macos, boost, homebrew, boost-python

I try to do python bindings on C++ using boost-python, but I can't compile and I can't find out why.

I'm using a code sample from boost-python `hello.cpp`:

```
// Copyright Ralf W. Grosse-Kunstleve 2002-2004. Distributed under the Boost
// Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

#include <boost/python/class.hpp>
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace { // Avoid cluttering the global namespace.

  // A friendly class.
  class hello
  {
    public:
      hello(const std::string& country) { this->country = country; }
      std::string greet() const { return "Hello from " + country; }
    private:
      std::string country;
  };

  // A function taking a hello object as an argument.
  std::string invite(const hello& w) {
    return w.greet() + "! Please come soon!";
  }
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(extending)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    class_<hello>("hello", init<std::string>())
        // Add a regular member function.
        .def("greet", &hello::greet)
        // Add invite() as a member of hello!
        .def("invite", invite)
        ;

    // Also add invite() as a regular function to the module.
    def("invite", invite);
}
```

With this `Jamroot`:

```
exe hello : hello.cpp ;
```

When I run `b2 --debug-configuration -n` everything seems fine:

```
$ ~/Sites/boost $ b2 --debug-configuration -n
notice: found boost-build.jam at /usr/local/share/boost-build/boost-build.jam
notice: loading Boost.Build from /usr/local/share/boost-build/kernel
notice: Searching /etc /Users/jauneau /usr/local/share/boost-build/kernel /usr/share/boost-build /usr/local/share/boost-build/kernel /usr/local/share/boost-build/util /usr/local/share/boost-build/build /usr/local/share/boost-build/tools /usr/local/share/boost-build/contrib /usr/local/share/boost-build/. for site-config configuration file site-config.jam .
notice: Configuration file site-config.jam not found in /etc /Users/jauneau /usr/local/share/boost-build/kernel /usr/share/boost-build /usr/local/share/boost-build/kernel /usr/local/share/boost-build/util /usr/local/share/boost-build/build /usr/local/share/boost-build/tools /usr/local/share/boost-build/contrib /usr/local/share/boost-build/. .
notice: Searching /Users/jauneau /usr/local/share/boost-build/kernel /usr/share/boost-build /usr/local/share/boost-build/kernel /usr/local/share/boost-build/util /usr/local/share/boost-build/build /usr/local/share/boost-build/tools /usr/local/share/boost-build/contrib /usr/local/share/boost-build/. for user-config configuration file user-config.jam .
notice: Loading user-config configuration file user-config.jam from /Users/jauneau/user-config.jam .
notice: OSX version on this machine is 10.7.5
notice: will use 'g++' for darwin, condition <toolset>darwin-4.2.1
notice: using strip for <toolset>darwin-4.2.1 at /usr/bin/strip
notice: using archiver for <toolset>darwin-4.2.1 at /usr/bin/libtool
notice: available sdk for <toolset>darwin-4.2.1/<macosx-version>10.6 at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk
notice: available sdk for <toolset>darwin-4.2.1/<macosx-version>10.7 at /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified version: "2.7"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "python"...
notice: [python-cfg] running command '"python" -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "python"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.2/include/python2.7"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib/python2.7/config" "/usr/local/bin/../Cellar/python/2.7.2/lib"
notice: [python-cfg] no framework directory found; using library path
...found 13 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
darwin.compile.c++ bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello.o

    "g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O0 -fno-inline -Wall -g -dynamic -no-cpp-precomp -gdwarf-2 -fexceptions -fPIC     -c -o "bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello.o" "hello.cpp"

darwin.link bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello

    "g++"  -o "bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello" "bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello.o"       -g 


...updated 2 targets...
```

But when I run b2 to compile my bindings he can't find python header files:

```
...found 13 targets...
...updating 2 targets...
darwin.compile.c++ bin/darwin-4.2.1/debug/hello.o
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/python/detail/prefix.hpp:13,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:8,
                 from hello.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:23: error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory
/usr/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:75:24: error: patchlevel.h: No such file or directory
/usr/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:78:2: error: #error Python 2.2 or higher is required for this version of Boost.Python.
/usr/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:142:21: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/object/class.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:13,
                 from hello.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:34: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
/usr/local/include/boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:41: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘(’ token
/usr/local/include/boost/python/instance_holder.hpp:45: error: ‘PyObject’ has not been declared
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/python/object/pointer_holder.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/object/class.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/python/class.hpp:13,
                 from hello.cpp:5:
...
```

I have installed both boost and boost-build using Homebrew.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

it may be related to the fact that you are using a homebrew python but Boost is linked to the system Python.